# How to compile a package which depends on @microsoft/*

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling, typescript

I'm trying to create a reusable SharePoint utility library.
I want to use heft to build the library, because it will deal with scss typings, and both cjs/esm outputs.

However, SharePoint's dependencies contain unpublished internal dependencies (that's causing a lot of troubles, but that's another story).
That should not, however, prevent compilation because these packages are already bundled and shipped as CJS.

When I use heft, however, I see heft trying to build source code of this packages, instead of just using its typing.

Error is :  `Error: node_modules/.pnpm/@microsoft+sp-core-library@1.16.1_@types+react-dom@17.0.22_@types+react@17.0.69_react-dom@17.0.2_react@17.0.2/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/dist/index-internal.d.ts:13:71 - (TS2307) Cannot find module '@ms/odsp-core-bundle' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I use the `@rushstack/hef-web-rig` package to simplify config.

I created a small repro: https://github.com/stevebeauge/heft-sp.git.

```
git clone https://github.com/stevebeauge/heft-sp.git
cd heft-sp
pnpm i
pnpm build
```

How can I solve my issue?

I also tried to manually compile (w/o heft) using: `pnpm tsc -b` but it does not compiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the missing piece:

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

in the tsconfig.json make the compiler ignore the dependencies in compiling.